# Angular2: how to add/change class to element on certain conditions

Tags: css, angular, styles, semantic-ui, ng-class

I'm developing a web application with Angular and Semantic-UI framework.

For adding a class to element on certain condition I have already used the following way:

```
[class.className]='condition'
```

Now I have more than one class name and I can't figure out how to deal with it.

So I tried to use `ngClass` as showed in this [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/DzxH2e).
As you can see here this solution doesn't work at all.

So, how to fix my Plunker to make it working?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can build a string containing several classes using [`[ngClass]`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html) here.

```
<div [ngClass]="('firstClass ' + (active ? 'secondClass' : ''))"></div>
```

In this case `firstClass` is the first class and active is a boolean that sets the `secondClass` class.

So, in your case your code can become:

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <div class="ui input" [ngClass]= "((myForm.controls.name.pending ? 'loading' : '') + 'secondClass')">
        <input id="name" [formControl]="myForm.controls.name">
    </div>
</div>
```

Remember to provide spaces between two consecutive classes.

**EDIT**

As for your plunker, you have got to add the `ngClass` statement as:

```
[ngClass]="[o.order === 'asc' ? 'chevron circle up': '' , o.order === 'desc' ? 'chevron circle down': '']"
```

Comment: Hi, have you read my question at the end? In the Plunker `ngClass` doesn't work.

Comment: Check edited answer. You can use both the syntaxes of writing `ngClass` as mentioned here.

Comment: Are you sure your syntax is right? It seems not to be correct.

Comment: Yes I am positive. You can try them in your plunker and let me know.

Comment: Nope, it will not work with your syntax, it should either be : `[ngClass]="[o.order === 'asc' ? 'chevron circle up': '' , o.order === 'desc' ? 'chevron circle down': '']"` or as I did in my plunker beolw instead.

Comment: Yes good correction. However, I find this easier to use: `[ngClass]="('firstClass ' + (active ? 'secondClass' : ''))"`

Comment: That doesn't matter with Plunker! The code with `[class.classname]` was just a sample! My question is related to Plunker. Anyway, thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`[ngClass]`](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/common/index/NgClass-directive.html)

```
<div class="field">
    <label for="name">Name:</label>
    <div class="ui input" [ngClass]="{loading : myForm.controls.name.pending}">
        <input id="name" [formControl]="myForm.controls.name">
    </div>
</div>
```

When the result of your test is `true` it will add the classes in your classes otherwise it **removes them** from the element

Comment: Hi, have you read my question at the end? In the Plunker ngClass doesn't work.

Comment: it is working in your plunker. The thing you don't get is that when ngClass is false **it removes** the classes from th span.

Comment: He're is your fixed plunker : https://plnkr.co/edit/XcwRdZ80UrVMG2mVAG8j?p=preview